# how to pass cell value to the shift function

Tags: python, pandas, variables, shift

how to pass a cell value in a pandas dataframe to the shift function?

here is some sample input:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0],
                        'y': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,10,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})

df['z'] = np.where(df['x'].shift(1) > 0, (50 - df['y'].shift(5)), np.nan)

print(df)

df['a'] = np.where(df['x'].shift(1) > 0, (50 - df['y'].shift(df['x'].shift(1).get_value())), np.nan)
```

here is the output:

```
   x     y     z
0  0   NaN   NaN
1  0   NaN   NaN
2  0   NaN   NaN
3  0  10.0   NaN
4  0   NaN   NaN
5  0   NaN   NaN
6  0   NaN   NaN
7  5   NaN   NaN
8  0   NaN  40.0
9  0   NaN   NaN

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\stocks\sandp500\stack overflow question 1.py", line 11, in <module>
    df['a'] = np.where(df['x'].shift(1) > 0, (50 - df['y'].shift(df['x'].shift(1).get_value())), np.nan)
TypeError: get_value() missing 1 required positional argument: 'label'
```

column "x" will either have a value of 0 or some integer from 1 to n.  these integers are the value I want to pass to the shift function to create column "z".  here in column "z" I am cheating by hard coding the "5" into the shift function.  column "a" is my attempt to pass a dynamic value from column "x" to the shift function.

i have tried dozens of variations on this over the last 48 hours and can't get anything to work.
does anyone have ideas?  thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the expected output for column `a`. Would be great if you can explain the logic behind its calculation as well.

Comment: the expected output of column "a" is what is currently shown in column "z" = all NaNs except for row 8 which would be 40.0.  the logic behind it is that anytime there is a non-zero value in column "x", the next row in column "z" is a simple subtraction of the column "y" value (shifted by the value of the column "x" variable integer).

Comment: Is there a logic behind this calculation?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you were trying to do is achievable with `df.apply`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0],
                        'y': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,10,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})
```

I think it is easier to follow the logic in a standalone function as opposed to a lambda:

```
def shifter(mydf):
    offset = int(mydf['offset'])
    if offset>0:
        val = 50 - df.shift(int(offset))['y'].loc[int(mydf['index'])]
    else:
        val = np.nan
    return val
```

I made a copy of the dataframe with the index as a column, and then because you're doing that extra `.shift(1)` on the "x" column, I made an auxiliary column called `offset` that just does that ahead of time:

```
df2 = df.reset_index()
df2['offset'] = df2['x'].shift(1).fillna(0)

print(df2)
   index  x     y  offset
0      0  0   NaN     0.0
1      1  0   NaN     0.0
2      2  0   NaN     0.0
3      3  0  10.0     0.0
4      4  0   NaN     0.0
5      5  0   NaN     0.0
6      6  0   NaN     0.0
7      7  5   NaN     0.0
8      8  0   NaN     5.0
9      9  0   NaN     0.0
```

Then, you can apply the shifter function on a row-wise basis. Note that it still makes reference to the original `df` dataframe within that function. It uses the values in the "index" column to find the adjusted row via `.loc` on the original dataframe.

```
df['z'] = df2.apply(shifter, axis=1)

print(df)
   x     y     z
0  0   NaN   NaN
1  0   NaN   NaN
2  0   NaN   NaN
3  0  10.0   NaN
4  0   NaN   NaN
5  0   NaN   NaN
6  0   NaN   NaN
7  5   NaN   NaN
8  0   NaN  40.0
9  0   NaN   NaN
```

Related, for reference, if you are just looking to grab offset values without the extra logic:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': [0,1,3,5,2,1,0,5,0,1],
                        'y': [2.0,4,3,10,1,77,28,56,42,48]})

def simple_shifter(mydf):
    offset = int(mydf['x'])
    val = df.shift(int(offset))['y'].loc[int(mydf['index'])]
    return val    

df3 = df.reset_index()
df['y_offset_by_x'] = df3.apply(simple_shifter, axis=1)

print(df)
   x     y  y_offset_by_x
0  0   2.0            2.0
1  1   4.0            2.0
2  3   3.0            NaN
3  5  10.0            NaN
4  2   1.0            3.0
5  1  77.0            1.0
6  0  28.0           28.0
7  5  56.0            3.0
8  0  42.0           42.0
9  1  48.0           42.0
```

Of course, if the dataframes are large there are speed optimizations to be made, but this should work.